# aot requires "component-relative" template urls?

Tags: angular

AOT requires "component-relative" template urls but I'm not exactly sure what's meant by this.  Can anyone here provide some additional insight on this? Here's an example of how my ng2 app is structured:

```
ng2
=> components
test-component.ts
=> templates
test.component.html
```

The template is referenced within the component like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    templateUrl: '../../ng2/templates/test.component.html'
})
```

Is this an example of a proper component-relative template url or do I need to change it in some way in order to support AOT?  If I'm referencing the template url in an appropriate way then what's a common scenario in which the templateUrl structure would work with JIT but not AOT?

Comment: Yes, that is component-relative, but structuring your project like that is unconventional; see https://angular.io/guide/styleguide.

Comment: thanks jon!  can u provide an example of a template reference that would *not* be component relative?  ie it work in jit but not aot?  I'm not sure how someone would configure the template url in a different way then I did in the example I provided, but I'd like to know what to look for in case I'm doing a code review sometime